# jsp iterator over list to get specific id

Tags: list, jsp, iterator, radio-button

I have below code to iterate over the list to get the radio button populate:

```
<s:iterator value="custData.custList" id="custNameDetail">          
<li>
<s:radio name="custname" list="#{'':custName}"  ></s:radio><s:property value="DescriptioMess"/>
</li>
</s:iterator>
```

Its working perfectly but I want to disable the first radio button. How can I iterate through list to get the specific ids and disable the first radio button?

I am getting below as the output while running the above code for all elements:

```
<input type="radio" name= "custname" id="custname" checked="checked" value>
```

I think the problem lies here. I should get the different ids for all and then only I can add disabled="disabled" for the first id.

Please let me know if you guys have come across this issue and you have any suggestions.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't working with JSPs for few years but isn't the syntax for variables `${variable}`? Like `="${someStruct.id}"`?

Posting your Java code may help to put specific answer...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a status variable that will give you information about the loop iteration you are on.

So you can do something like this

```
<s:iterator value="custData.custList" id="custNameDetail" status="loopStatus">          
<li>
      <s:if test="#loopStatus.first == true">    //make it disabled
         <s:radio name="custname" list="#{'':custName}"  ></s:radio><s:property       value="DescriptioMess"/>
     </s:if>
     <s:else>
         <s:radio name="custname" list="#{'':custName}"  ></s:radio><s:property       value="DescriptioMess"/>
     </s:else>
</li>
</s:iterator>
```

See [here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-iterator-tag-example/) for more information.